# Rotary encoder working on Pi 3 but not on Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, wiringpi

I'm trying to read an encoder switch using wiringPi (latest, 2.52). Whenever there is an edge on either of the encoding pins a or b, I store a snapshot of the state of both pins on two bits:

`int val = 2*digitalRead(pina) + digitalRead(pinb)`

A separate process then filters out repeating states and then looks for these patterns in the data :

- `0 -> 1 -> 3` is a turn in one direction
- `0 -> 2 -> 3` is a turn in the other

This works great on my Pi 3, but on the Pi 4, the state `3` never appears. The sequences look like:

`0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 2`...

instead of

`0 1 3 2 0 2 3 1 0 1 3 2`...

In other words, the pins a and b are never read as high at the same time. Since the states `1` and `2` show up, I know (think?) that the pins are being read correctly. These tests are being done on the same hardware setup by swapping out the Pi and nothing else.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you aware that WiringPi was deprecated http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/ and may not work with newer boards and OS changes?

Comment: No idea. However it is never a good idea to read the state of a GPIO in a userland interrupt under Linux. It may have happened many milliseconds before.

Comment: ...So a better idea would be to manually track the state of a pin based on the interrupt firing (a pin in a low state transitions to a high state on edge, and vice versa), and use those states in the handlers.  This will reflect the sequence of events communicated by the encoder even if the timing is not millisecond perfect (which in a significant sense userland code can never be anyway).

Comment: @Andyroo Yes. But the 2.52 version works on Pi 4

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah but unfortunately wiringPi will only allow me one callback per pin, on either rising, falling or both edges. Since I listen for both edges, I know don't from which state I came from (no info is passed to the callback). Not ideal clearly, but I'm having trouble believing that this is what's wrong here.

Comment: My point is *a pin in a high state transitions to a low state on edge*, so unless the pins are like Schrodinger's cat, you know what their state is before the encoder starts and the interrupts start firing.  You can track state that way, presuming there are no missed interrupts (which may or may not be a feature of wiringPi), or that you need to be able to start this code with the rotary encoder in motion, in which case you won't be able to reliably get state before setting the handlers without the possibility of it changing before the handler is set.

Comment: To maybe explain that a bit further: A pin in a high state that transitions rapidly to low and back to high again should fire the interrupt twice, even if the whole event is actually over by the time the code runs.   So while the timing can't be perfect, the sequence of events can followed accurately.

Comment: @goldilocks True but what bothers me is that if there ever is a missed interrupt, then the deduced state will be the opposite of reality until the next missed interrupt. At least with what I have here, even though the risk of getting an out of date measurement is higher, the consequences of that error will not carry on to future measurements. (if I'm being honest, its hard to imagine ever missing an interrupt if the callback does nothing more than storing a state)

Comment: If the measurement depends on accurately knowing the state of one pin *when the other pin changes state*, then you don't really have a choice here: As joan points out, your current method won't do that.  Because you are checking the state of the pins in the handler, this may not reflect the actual state of the pins when the interrupt triggered, and it may in fact not represent their simultaneous state at any point in time (since it takes two reads to get both); this is the reason for the problem in your question...

Comment: ...However, if all that matters at any point is the actual state of the pins *when you read them*, none of that matters (and neither does the apparent problem in the question); just read the pins at whatever point and act accordingly. I've never used a rotary encoder so can't help you with that part.

Comment: wait for rising edge of `A` then check state of `B` .... state of `B` indicates the direction of rotation

Comment: Linux quite often loses GPIO interrupts when they are happening frequently (it only buffers a few).  It probably doesn't apply to your rotary encoder problem.

Comment: @jsotola That's my problem, B is always low when A is high

Comment: @goldilocks It is indeed the sequence of states that I need, not the state of any given time. Cheap rotary switches are extremely messy, mine generates hundreds of "bounce" contacts on a single increment, probably many more missed by the OS. I was just happy to have such a small bit of code perform so well despite the bad approach, and I'm still puzzled as to why it fails so completely on the pi 4. But yeah, I can't really be asking why code that shouldn't be trusted isn't working.

Comment: @schmop no, you are not understanding ... not `when A is high`  ... it is `when A transitions from low to high` ... also known as `rising edge` ... it is a specific, single point in time